# Live Server MySQL connection time out, on Google Cloud Instances

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 203
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /var/www/html/medical-survey/application/models/Userdata_model.php
>   Line: 8 Function: database
>
> File: /var/www/html/medical-survey/application/controllers/Admins.php
>   Line: 9 Function: model
>
> File: /var/www/html/medical-survey/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

and

> A Database Error Occurred Unable to connect to your database server
>   using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 357

When I attempt to load my page that uses the database, it shows this error

database.php:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| DATABASE CONNECTIVITY SETTINGS
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file will contain the settings needed to access your database.
|
| For complete instructions please consult the 'Database Connection'
| page of the User Guide.
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| EXPLANATION OF VARIABLES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|       ['dsn']      The full DSN string describe a connection to the database.
|       ['hostname'] The hostname of your database server.
|       ['username'] The username used to connect to the database
|       ['password'] The password used to connect to the database
|       ['database'] The name of the database you want to connect to
|       ['dbdriver'] The database driver. e.g.: mysqli.
|                       Currently supported:
|                                cubrid, ibase, mssql, mysql, mysqli, oci8,
|                                odbc, pdo, postgre, sqlite, sqlite3, sqlsrv
|       ['dbprefix'] You can add an optional prefix, which will be added
|                                to the table name when using the  Query Builder class
|       ['pconnect'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether to use a persistent connection
|       ['db_debug'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether database errors should be displayed.
|       ['cache_on'] TRUE/FALSE - Enables/disables query caching
|       ['cachedir'] The path to the folder where cache files should be stored
|       ['char_set'] The character set used in communicating with the database
|       ['dbcollat'] The character collation used in communicating with the database
|                                NOTE: For MySQL and MySQLi databases, this setting is only used
|                                as a backup if your server is running PHP < 5.2.3 or MySQL < 5.0.7
|                                (and in table creation queries made with DB Forge).
|                                There is an incompatibility in PHP with mysql_real_escape_string() which
|                                can make your site vulnerable to SQL injection if you are using a
                            multi-byte character set and are running versions lower than these.
|                                Sites using Latin-1 or UTF-8 database character set and collation are unaffected.
|       ['swap_pre'] A default table prefix that should be swapped with the dbprefix
|       ['encrypt']  Whether or not to use an encrypted connection.
|
|                       'mysql' (deprecated), 'sqlsrv' and 'pdo/sqlsrv' drivers accept TRUE/FALSE
|                       'mysqli' and 'pdo/mysql' drivers accept an array with the following options:
|
|                               'ssl_key'    - Path to the private key file
|                               'ssl_cert'   - Path to the public key certificate file
|                               'ssl_ca'     - Path to the certificate authority file
|                               'ssl_capath' - Path to a directory containing trusted CA certificates in PEM format
|                               'ssl_cipher' - List of *allowed* ciphers to be used for the encryption, separated by colons (':')
|                               'ssl_verify' - TRUE/FALSE; Whether verify the server certificate or not
|
|       ['compress'] Whether or not to use client compression (MySQL only)
|       ['stricton'] TRUE/FALSE - forces 'Strict Mode' connections
|                                                       - good for ensuring strict SQL while developing
|       ['ssl_options'] Used to set various SSL options that can be used when making SSL connections.
|       ['failover'] array - A array with 0 or more data for connections if the main should fail.
|       ['save_queries'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether to "save" all executed queries.
|                               NOTE: Disabling this will also effectively disable both
|                               $this->db->last_query() and profiling of DB queries.
|                               When you run a query, with this setting set to TRUE (default),
|                               CodeIgniter will store the SQL statement for debugging purposes.
|                               However, this may cause high memory usage, especially if you run
|                               a lot of SQL queries ... disable this to avoid that problem.
|
| The $active_group variable lets you choose which connection group to
| make active.  By default there is only one group (the 'default' group).
|
| The $query_builder variables lets you determine whether or not to load
| the query builder class.
*/
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
$db['default']['options'] = array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5);

$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'SERVER_IP_REDACTED:SERVER_PORT_REDACTED',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'survey',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I had already tried using 'hostname' => 'localhost', and it also did not work

Comment: Is there a password to your database??

Comment: no, there isn't any for user root

Comment: Can you configure a simple database connection in core PHP and try connecting to the database? I think that will give you the exact issue and you will be able to trace it accordingly.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you might need to connect with the support team.

Comment: @beingprabhu Do you mean create a php file calling the database or checking the configs of the database in the php files?

Comment: Create a PHP file outside the application with MySQL connection having your database credentials. Check if the connection succeeds. If not then contact your support team.

Comment: I suspect there might be an IP restriction which is not letting your application to connect with the database.

Comment: Where are you running the PHP code(a VM your localhost, App Engine)? and where does this MySQL instance resides(CloudSQL, a VM)?

Comment: @JoséSoní MySQL is located in the VM under the folder /etc/.. while the PHP code is also in the VM under the /var/.. file

Comment: @beingprabhu I tried running a new fresh codeigniter with the same database and it has no problem loading it, maybe it might be a configuration that I had changed that mess it up

Comment: Okay. Cool. Glad to hear your issue is fixed. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved it, I made a new user and grant them permission to the database. Then use that user and it worked.

> 'hostname' => 'localhost',
>
> 'username' => 'new_user',
>
> 'password' => 'new_password'

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting you hostname same as your cloud instance IP address

`'hostname' => 'GOOGLE_CLOUD_INSTANCE_IP_ADDRESS'`

Example :

`'hostname' => '10.0.0.5'`